# whole body workout routine, 3 times/ week for a 53 years male

Tags: workout-routines, compound-exercises

I am 53 years old, male, 82 kg and BMI of 26, with an abdominal girth of 100 cm. I am a very skinny person, and frankly, I am ashamed of my muscle size, especially the upper part of my body. I started regular exercise last April, and presently I train every other day by dividing upper and lower body exercise one after another. I got some confidence, built some muscles, lost some abdominal fat and feeling great. However, I think the routines are repetitive for most of the muscle groups, and I wish to have a whole body routine, preferably compound one for three times a week with 60 to 90 minutes per session.  Please look for my current workout routine below.  I prepared this list based on reading different books and online forums.

Could anyone recommend a simplified workout based on the attached list or any alternative ones?

```
Upper body exercise

    Triceps Dip Machine
        Straight Bar Cable Tricep Extension
        Pushdown
    Back    Lat pulldown
        Single-Arm Bent Over Row (dumbbell row)
        Seated Cable Rows
    Chest   Incline Dumbbell chest  Press
        Seated Machine Chest Press  
        Cable Crossover
    Shoulder    Dumbbell Shoulder Press
        Dumbbell Upright Row
        Machine shoulder press
    Biceps  EZ  bar curl
        Hammer Curls with Rope
        Hammer curl

Lower  body exercise    
    Legs        
        Leg Press Exercise
        Seated Leg Curl
        Leg Extensions
        dumbbell  lunge
        Lying Leg Curls
        Calf Raises

    Abdominals
        Ab Crunch Machine
        Cable Crunch
        Dumbbell Side Bends
        Flutter kick
        Plank
```

Answer (score 1):

[STRONGLIFTS](http://stronglifts.com/)

Equipment: A gym with a barbell, bench, deadlift platform & squat rack.

Week A: On Monday, Weds and Fri:

- Squat 5x5
- Bench Press 5x5
- Barbell Row 5x5
- An Ab exercise (Hollow body hold, captains chair, ab wheel rollouts)

Week B: On Monday, Weds and Fri

- Squat 5x5
- Overhead Press 5x5
- Deadlift 1x5 (1 set of 5)
- An Ab exercise (Hollow body hold, captains chair, ab wheel rollouts)

Alternate week A and B

If you can complete a workout then add 5lbs/1.25kg for that exercise next time. If you fail, try 3x again and if you stall then deload by 10%.